# The phrase "Thank you kindly"

Tags: phrases

If the phrase "Thank you kindly,..." is considered archaic, could someone suggest an alternative?

Thanks

Bill

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "archaic".  It's a bit over-formal for modern use, and the etymology of the expression is a bit foggy, but it still has it's uses, when one wants to be a bit formal without bowing and scraping.

Answer (score 0):

It could be replaced with "Highly obliged" or simply "Obliged" but even these words are considered overly formal and archaic. In modern English, one simply uses "Thank you", "Thanks a lot" or rarely "Many thanks".

Answer (score 0):

Two common simple ones:

> Much appreciated.
>
> Many thanks.